# can getting sensor data take less CPU time?

Tags: android

I'm building a App the requires high resolution on one of the acceleration sensors, but no data at all from any others. so, when I'm listening to the event, I'm doing the following:

```
 mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer,
      SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
```

the thing is, the event shoots every time a sensor changes, and preforms a check - lots of CPU time wasted, that could be used for better things.

Is there a way to save this CPu time?

Comment: i don't want a function to be called for every sensor, just the one that interests me.

Comment: what intrest you? orientation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to listen to one sensor:

```
    sensorManager = (SensorManager)context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    accSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, accSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
```

Now as to performance, in my experience even fastest will not have a major impact on performance but there are some thins to remember. Values as they arrive should be immediately dumped into another thread for processing. Doing all the processing in the sensor thread can impact performance or delivery time of future samples.

Copy the values out of the SensorData and don't keep a reference to the values array. Those are part of a fixed pool that may get re-used later and you don't want those changed out from under your code.

SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST is generally not suitable if you have any care about precision. The speed comes at a price of having jittery data. Dump the sensor data to the lof on fastest and put the device on a stable flat surface. It still dumps out tons of samples because it thinks there are lots of changes to report while with SENSOR_DELAY_GAME the samples slow way down because there is nothing to report and that's correct. Motorola is another story with this since they aggressively clamp down on duplicate samples and setting a device on a flat surface will see the number of reported samples go to 0.

Answer (score 1):

try another flag:

```
SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST    //get sensor data as fast as possible
SENSOR_DELAY_GAME       //rate suitable for games
SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL     //rate (default) suitable for screen orientation changes
SENSOR_DELAY_UI         //rate suitable for the user interface
```

Comment: i want the trigger as fast as I can, but just for one specific sensor.

Comment: Even just for the accelerometer, it's going to be ridiculously fast. The accelerometer is most likely the fastest-updating sensor, because even the slightest, most imperceptible movement will set it off. `SENSOR_DELAY_GAME` normally fires at 30-60Hz, depending on device. If you need it faster than that(you shouldn't for most things), you'll have to sacrifice CPU time.

Answer (score 1):

Since API 3, you can register for a single sensor. Use the approach bellow:

```
    try {
        sensorMgr = (SensorManager) context.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

        sensors = sensorMgr.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        if (sensors.size() > 0) sensorGrav = sensors.get(0);

        sensorMgr.registerListener(this, sensorGrav, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

    } catch (Exception ex1) {
        try {
            if (sensorMgr != null) {
                sensorMgr.unregisterListener(this, sensorGrav);
                sensorMgr = null;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex2) {
            ex2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and the listener will be called only for changes in the acceleration sensors.

good luck.

Answer (score 1):

> i don't want a function to be called for every sensor, just the one that interests me

That's the way Android works, but it only happens if you register more than one sensor. In case you want to read more than one sensor, what you can do is use a `switch-case` to filter your favorite sensor.

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    synchronized (this){
        switch (event.sensor.getType()) {
            case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
                //Do your magic here
                break;
            case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
                System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, magneticFieldValues, 0,
                        event.values.length);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

> Is there a way to save this CPU time?

Do you REALLY need `SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST`? The fastest you read, the fastest you drain the battery. If you changed it, you will save CPU time because you won't have to read the sensor as many times as you do when you use `SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST` nor you won't execute that many time the `onSensorChanged` method.

Remember that using `FASTEST, GAME, NORMAL or UI` doesn't mean how fast you will get a data when a change occurs. It means how often the device reads the registered sensor(s) (it doesn't matter if the values are the same or not) and executes the `onSensorChanged` method if the last value is different from the just-read-value (both from the same sensor).